# Get updates ... OK-box does not disappear

Tags: bug

When clicking on "following" of a question after the suggestive "Get updates..." ok/box, that box does not disappear and the subsequent boxes that appear show below that pesky box. So I cannot read them.  Only going to another page makes this box disappear. FF 74.0

Comment: This seems to be a network wide issue. Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345947/get-updates-on-questions-and-answers-pop-up-can-no-longer-be-dismissed-by-clicki

Comment: It seems to work again now.